# Appium Error: Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested address is not available

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I have a mac and I'm trying to run Appium to run iOS tests.

I'm using the Appium app for this, I looked on the troubleshoot section and I think everything is setup as it should, but the app give me this error: 
"Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested address is not available"

Someone know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/4s5zQ4sBabo).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that from error you are using the IP address or port number that is used by another process in the system, Simply kill that process that using the same port number that you are using or try to give following IP address and port number
 1. IP address  : 127.0.0.1
 2. Port number : any thing that is not in use say 5000

Comment: thank you for the answer, however the question was 9 month ago.
I already finished the project without Appium.
But again I appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Hi @Blacky, just curious to know, how did you complete your framework without appium ?

Comment: I used Instruments instead.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the ipaddress to the systems current IP address and  changed port to 4725 and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If appium is having that issue i think its from the IP address you are setting it to. You might have more than one instance running by accident, or you simply need to give it a different IP and port number when configuring.

Answer (score 0):

Start the Windows Task Manager by pressing `ctrl+alt+del` (or open up Activity Monitor on your Mac). Under Processes tab kill the `node.exe` process. Try to start the Appium server again.

Solution from SO post : [Appium: Couldn't start the appium server in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613119/appium-couldnt-start-the-appium-server-in-windows)